# New not equal symbol

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

Can you help me draw the slash sign?

`\draw[fill=black,rounded corners=0.17pt] %(?,?) rectangle ++(?,?);`
[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\usepackage{tikz}
%
\newcommand{\mynotequalsymbol}{      
\hspace{1.1mm}\tikz[baseline]{
  %
  \draw[fill=black,rounded corners=0.17pt]
  (1.1,0.16) rectangle ++(0.22,0.01);
  %
  \draw[fill=black,rounded corners=0.17pt]
  (1.1,0.09) rectangle ++(0.22,0.01);
  %
  %\draw[fill=black,rounded corners=0.17pt]
  %(?,?) rectangle ++(?,?);%
}\hspace{1.1mm}}
%
\newcommand{\myneq}{\mynotequalsymbol}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$$2 \myneq 3$$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So you were asking for the coordinates of the rotated line? If so, just wondering: how can that be a problem?

Comment: Yes i am asking it. Problem because I couldn't :) @MS-DPT

Comment: as I said yesterday if can ask that yiur accounts be  merged. you would be able to edit your own post. Currently your edit as Pitaya88 is blocked for review as the question is posted as cufcuf

Comment: I understand sir @David Carlisle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`rectangle` is only for drawing rectangles(with vertical and horizontal sides) - you are misusing it to draw essential a line.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\usepackage{tikz}
%
\newcommand{\mynotequalsymbol}{      
\hspace{1.1mm}\tikz[baseline, line width=0.7 pt, line cap=round]{
  \draw (1.1,0.16) -- ++(0.21,0);
  \draw (1.1,0.09) -- ++(0.21,0);
  \draw (1.15,0.05) -- ++(0.12,0.15);
}\hspace{1.1mm}}
%
\newcommand{\myneq}{\mynotequalsymbol}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$$2 \myneq 3$$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: 2 notequal 3]

Comment: You are right. I had to try to make the corners round. Thanks for help

Comment: I vote up your nice answer. Why do you put the `$$...$$`?

Comment: @Sebastiano:  I did not :o)

Comment: Ah...It has written by the user. :-)